# Generate a list of strings from another list using python random and eliminate duplicates

Tags: python-3.x, list, random

I have the following list:

`original_list = [('Anger', 'Envy'), ('Anger', 'Exasperation'), ('Joy', 'Zest'), ('Sadness', 'Suffering'), ('Joy', 'Optimism'), ('Surprise', 'Surprise'), ('Love', 'Affection')]`

I am trying to create a `random` list comprising of the 2nd element of the tuples (of the above list) using the `random` method in such a way that *duplicate values appearing as the first element are only considered once*.

That is, the final list I am looking at, will be:

`random_list = [Exasperation, Suffering, Optimism, Surprise, Affection]`

So, in the new list `random_list`, strings `Envy` and `Zest` are eliminated (as they are appearin the the original list **twice**). And the process has to randomize the result, i.e. with each iteration would produce a different list of **Five** elements.

May I ask somebody to show me the way how may I do it?

Comment: what do you mean with "each iteration": iteration of eliminating duplicates OR iteration under finally obtained `random_list` ?

Comment: Perhaps you want `list(dict(random.sample(original_list, len(original_list))).values())` ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I am sorry - I think I was not clear enough. I want to randomize the `original_list` by removing duplicates (at random) and then finally append in `random_list`. Say, there are `n` tuples in the list. I want only `p` samples (`p < n`).

Comment: @AndrejKesely I am getting error: `TypeError: Population must be a sequence or set.  For dicts, use list(d).`

Comment: @LovePutin So `original_list` is a dictionary, not a list?

Comment: @AndrejKesely I am generating a qs on the model and then transforming the `qs` into a list using `list(qs)`. Using the same `list` I am able to generate a random sample using `get_random_emot_sub_grp = random.sample(list_qs_emot_sub_grp, 3)` without error. I am not sure what's happening? And the result I am getting in terminal is `[('Anger', 'Exasperation'), ('Love', 'Affection'), ('Joy', 'Contentment')]`, i.e. the **three** randomly generated elements.

Comment: @AndrejKesely I am so sorry - In my hurry I was using the queryset (for your instant example), and not the `list`. (Lots of cobwebs gathered through my futile effort - and everything is spinning). I don't know how to thank you. And... It Works!!! I don't know how to say this - if you could please give me a bit of an idea how the code works here. THANKS.

Comment: @AndrejKesely If you don't mind, could you please add your solution as an answer so that I may close the question. Thanks again.

Comment: @LovePutin I've posted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dictionary to filter the duplicates from `original_list` (shuffled before with `random.sample`):

```py
import random

original_list = [
    ("Anger", "Envy"),
    ("Anger", "Exasperation"),
    ("Joy", "Zest"),
    ("Sadness", "Suffering"),
    ("Joy", "Optimism"),
    ("Surprise", "Surprise"),
    ("Love", "Affection"),
]

out = list(dict(random.sample(original_list, len(original_list))).values())
print(out)
```

Prints (for example):

```
['Optimism', 'Envy', 'Surprise', 'Suffering', 'Affection']
```